# Marionette.js jquery form submit removes page data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm working on a project with the following setup for a form submission which creates a POST that downloads a file

app ->

```
.setHandler 'eventForForm'
controller.submitForm()
```

controller ->

```
formView = newFormView
 collection = collectionToUse
```

header ->

```
event: 'click': 'buttonClick'
buttonClick ->
 triggerCallback to app for submit form
```

headerDom

```
<div><a href="#">Button to Submit</a></div>
```

newFormView

```
init ->
  submitForm()

submitForm ->
  $form = $('<form></form>')
  #code that adds it to the page with data required and css

  $form.submit()
  $form.remove() #remove it from dom
```

Everything works okay...Events are triggered, data is correct, and the form is submitted and the file is downloaded.

However after the .submit() event it doesn't really do a full page refresh just clears out all the data populated in the dom (the page is blank).  But it hasn't navigated away from the page and it doesn't do a page refresh (which corrects the data missing as the views are then repopulated.

Not sure whats really going on as the setup of the views and event handlers seems correct.

Marionette.js version -> 1.8.0, jquery -> version 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

If you want a page refresh why dont you just add a

```
window.location.reload()
```

call to the end of your submitForm function?